# androidStudio Invoke the assembleRelease build task Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited

Tags: android-studio

```
Executing external task 'assembleRelease'...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:preBuild
:preReleaseBuild
:checkReleaseManifest
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-hdpi/shadow_left.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-xhdpi/list_empty.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-mdpi/push.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-xhdpi/default_ptr_flip.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-hdpi/ios_thumb.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-xhdpi/button_bar_blak_off.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-hdpi/shadow_bottom.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-nodpi/emoji_1f4bd.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-hdpi/shadow_right.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-xhdpi/list_error.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-nodpi/emoji_1f555.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-ldpi/push.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-xhdpi/button_bar_blak_on.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
/Users/shumizuri/Documents/mituworkspace/LovePractice_ForAndroid/res/drawable-hdpi/push.png: libpng warning: iCCP: Not recognizing known sRGB profile that has been edited
```

how can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such a problem, you should use the software to save the pictures as PNG format.